# Obtener la fecha más reciente de una columna de un CSV con Numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Quisiera saber cómo puedo obtener la fecha más reciente de un .csv con Numpy (no tengo permitido usar pandas).
Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera obtener la fecha más reciente de la columna `fec_venc` por ende me debería entregar como resultado el valor `06/01/2022`.

Tengo ese archivo csv, lo primero que hice fue leer el archivo:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

#Leer el archivo CSV
data = np.genfromtxt('archivo.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Y ahora necesito obtener esa fecha. Por favor su ayuda!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es, al obtener las columnas convierte tu columna fec_venc a `datetime` luego puedes utilizar la función `max()` y luego conviertes el resultado a `string`

Para convertir la columna a `datetime` puedes utilizar el argumento `converters`

Para que cada columna sea devuelta como un `array` puedes utilizar el argumento `unpack`

Ejemplo funcionando:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

str2date = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
data = np.genfromtxt('archivo.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, unpack=True, encoding="UTF-8", converters={5:str2date})
print(max(data[5]).strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
06/01/2022
```

**Edición:**

Para hacer lo mismo pero en lugar de utilizar el número de la columna utilizar el nombre de la columna puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

str2date = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
data = np.genfromtxt('archivo.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, unpack=False, encoding="UTF-8", converters={'fec_venc':str2date})
print(max(data['fec_venc']).strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: Me funciona perfecto de esa forma, pero en caso de querer realizar lo mismo pero con la columna específica fec_venc en vez de que sea por la posición data[5] ¿Cómo podría realizarse?. Muchas gracias desde ya!!

Comment: Buen día, edité la respuesta y agregué como hacerlo con el nombre de la columna

Comment: Muchas graciaaaas, ahí me funcionó perfecto!! :D